# is it necessary to use php artisan serve every time?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I use

```
php artisan serve
```

every time to use Laravel. Is it necessary to use this command every time for using Laravel?

Comment: Of course not, that's just a way to launch a development server.  I suggest you read the docs, Laravel also has Homestead and Valet (for Mac).  You wouldn't want to use artisan serve in production.

Comment: Install a `WAMP`, `MAMP` or `LAMP` (or similar) stack as a local development environment, configure a url like `myapp.com` to point to your project's `public` folder, and navigate away.

Comment: but i am using it on windows

Comment: @HarjotSingh You can install some software (like Homestead, WAMP, XAMPP or MAMP) and use that to create a webserver on your computer. Doesn't matter that you're using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure nginx or apache2, so wont need to run the command each time. 
In production you will need a real http server.
try [this to configure apache for laravel project](https://phpraxis.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/steps-for-configuring-laravel-on-apache-http-server/), [or this for nginx with laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/deployment)

Comment: He means for local development, not server. These solutions would be perfect for a webserver, not a local one

Answer (score 0):

in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` open the hosts file. Add this to the bottom of the content.

```
192.168.1.120(Your local IP)    test.local
```

save the file.

Then open the conf file from your apache server. For example if you are using xampp, in the `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra` open the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Add this to the bottom of the content.

```
<VirtualHost example.local:80>
      DocumentRoot "C:/yourprojectfolder/public/"
      ServerAdmin admin@example.local
      ServerName example.local

       <Directory "C:/yourprojectfolder/public/">
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride all
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Then you can access the project without artisan. In the browser open the http://example.local/

ta da!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side scripting language and needs a special environment to run. It's a http server.

So the answer is yes. You have to use a server to run application.

Laravel has one built in which you run by:

```
php artisan serve
```

Of course you can use another web server like Apache, Ngix but this is question to another topic something like "How to run Laravel app on Apache".

Comment: yes  i have xampp in pc, if i want to use laravel i first start xampp then use php artisan serve in cmd ... if i close the cmd the framework did not  works